Big Fish precursor?
When I saw the 2003 movie Big Fish, I immediately thought to myself: I know that plot from a different movie!  But in all commentaries that I have read about Big Fish, I have not seen any references to the earlier movie I remember seeing with the same plot.
So, what is the movie I am thinking of?
Again, there is a man who tells tall tales about his time in an extraordinary circus, with extraordinary characters.  In this older movie, the son is quite young.  The movie ends with the little boy finding the abandoned circus which his father talked about, and realizing that the stories of his father were not tall tales after all.

A couple of months before Big Fish was released, a TV movie called Wilder Days aired with an eerily similar plot: Peter Falk starred as an old man telling stories about his days on a circus boat, and a young Josh Hutcherson and Tim Daly were the grandson and son who don't believe his tales but that come across that circus boat in the end. Might be what you're looking for. You can find it here.

@Walt: That is exactly the movie I was thinking of.  Do you want to make it into an official answer so you can get the credit?

@Itcomdata No problem, will do. Posted as a comment first because it seemed a bit of a stretch... Glad you found it. :)

Wilder Days, a TV movie from 2003:

After Chris's grandfather took a nasty fall down some stairs he was sent to an old folks home. He did not want to be there so he took Chris on a trip without asking his dad first. His dad went through a lot of trouble trying to find them.

Peter Falk starred as the grandfather who tells tall tales about his days on a circus boat; his grandson (Josh Hutcherson) and son (Tim Daly) didn't believe him but in the end found the boat and realized he was telling the truth. This particular plot point is strangely similar to the plot of Big Fish which came out a few months later; Chalk it up to the Twin Film phenomenon, I guess. Here are some scenes:




Walt, I've been meaning to ask, how the hell do you get that embed code on your answer??

Do you mean the Youtube video? Just add the link, it's embedded automatically now.

^ wow really? Thanks, that has to be the one thing I haven't tried :D
